# How to demonstrate a set is decidible, semi-decidible or not semi-decidible?

Tags: computation-theory, decidable

I have been asked to prove if the following set is decidible, semi-decidible or not semi-decidible:

[image]

In other words, it is the set of inputs such that exists a Turing Machine encoded with the natural y with input p that returns its input.

Consider the set K as the set of naturals such that the Turing machine encoded with x and input x stops. This is demonstrated to be a non-decidible set.

[image]

I think that what I need is to find a reduction of K to L, but I don't know how to prove that L is decidible, semi-decidible or not semi-decidible.

Comment: Is the following restatement of your desired set accurate? "The set of all natural numbers {n1, n2, …} encoding Turing machines {m1, m2, …} which eventually halt (or halt-accept only and not halt-reject) and which, after halting, have the same tape contents they were given as input." So the TM that immediately halt-accepts is an example of the kind of TMs your numbers encode, but the TM that changes the first input symbol and then halt-accepts is not?

Answer (score 1):

L may not *look* decidable at first glance, because there is this nasty unbounded quantifier included, which seems to make necessary a possibly infinite search when you look for a y satisfying the condition for a specific p.

However, the answer is much simpler: There is a turing machine M which always returns its input, i.e. M(p) = p holds for *all* p in the considered language. Let y be a code of M. Then you can use this same y for all p, showing that L contains *all* words of the language. Hence L is of course decidable.

In fact, this is an example to demonstrate the [principle of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensionality) (if two sets have the same elements and one is decidable, then the other is decidable too, even if it doesn't look so).